# Which still wants vs which still want

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, prepositional-phrases, syntactic-analysis

Which one is correct?

1) Pick those pieces of your heart which still **wants** to be happy , or

2) Pick those pieces of your heart which still **want** to be happy.

Answer (score 2):

"Pick those pieces of your heart which still want to be happy" is correct.

"Want" matches with the plural noun, "pieces." A piece wants, whereas pieces want.

Answer (score -1):

Well the subject is "pieces of your heart" so I'd say "still want" though it doesn't make much sense.